# Electric current through wire

Tags: electric-current, charge

If you have a wire of area A and length x with a constant current flowing through it, is it reasonable to say that:

$I=\dfrac{dQ}{dt}\Rightarrow dQ=Idt\Rightarrow Q=It \Rightarrow Q=\dfrac{Ix}{v_d}$?

Comment: Did you mean $Q=\frac {Ix} {v_d}$?

Comment: The units on the two sides of the equations dont match....So no..

Comment: Either way, no. The time the current flows through the circuit has nothing to do with drift velocity. What meaning do you associate with "x"?

Comment: @nasu, the question is about "a wire of ... length *x*".

Comment: Sorry, I meant Q=Ix/v_d.

Comment: @Photon 3 - It does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is no. Current is not defined as the velocity of charge in a conductor. "Electric current through a surface is defined as the rate of charge transport through that surface". (Re NCEE reference handbook for the PE FE exam in Electrical and Computer Engineering). Picture yourself looking edgewise at the cross section of a conductor and watching the electrons go by. The number of coulombs of electrons that pass through the surface per second is the current in amperes.

Comment: But if the charges are moving with some drift velocity $v_d$ over some distance $dx$ through a surface, then the time it takes to travel that distance is $dt=\frac{dx}{v_d}$ Since current is "defined as the rate of charge transport through that surface", then $I=\frac{dQ}{dt}$ where $dQ$ is the amount of charge that flows through the surface in time $dt$. In other words, $dQ=I \space dt=\frac{I\space dx}{v_d}$ I don't understand why that is wrong.

Comment: What was the form of the original question (it didn't keep a copy), before it was edited? I may have answered the original version. I often formulate my answers off line and post them later (possibly missing a subsequent edit).

Comment: @BobD In the original question, I was missing in the final formula, so the units did not match.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens - The time in the Q=It has nothing to do with how long it takes to travel some distance with the drift velocity. You can have conductors with various drift velocities (and various lengths) and still carrying the same current so the same charge will be transported in a given time. You should be aware of the physical meaning of your variables. Not everything noted as "t" and having dimensions of time have same meaning and can be plugged in any equation containing time (and make sense).

Comment: Looking at your question again it seems I misread it. I thought you were equating current with drift velocity. Clearly you weren’t. Sorry about that and your conclusion is correct. Feel free to withdraw your accept.

Regarding Nasu comment to Aaron Stevens, I believe $v_d$ in the equation is meant to be the average drift velocity of the charge carriers. On that basis, and assuming current is not varying in time, I believe $Q=It$ would be correct.

Comment: @nasu This is why I was talking in terms of $dx$, $dt$ and $dQ$. The OP is asking about a single material. I am aware of the physical meaning of my variables.

Comment: @nasu Would you be more satisfied if $dQ$ was written in terms of the carrier density for the material?

Comment: Should you edit your answer to reflect this?

Comment: @Bob D - Q=It is correct independently of the meaning of the parameters in what follows after Q=It. The problem is that the "t" here is not (necessarily) related to the drift velocity or the length of the wire. It is an arbitrary time. Unless you really want to calculate the charge carried by a current I during the time it will take to travel along the wire with the drift velocity (for that current).

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments on other answers, let's be a bit more careful.

Let's say we have a uniform current density $J=\frac IA\space$  as well as a uniform charge carrier density $n=\frac NV\space$  Where 
$N$ is the number of charge carriers in the volume $V$ of the wire.

Now let's think about how much charge $dQ$ passes through a cross section of the wire with area $A$. Well the amount of charge in some volume $dV$ is ${dQ}=qn{dV}=nqA{dx}$, where $dx$ is a small length along the wire, and $q$ is the amount of charge in one charge carrier. Now if the charge carriers are moving with some average drift velocity $v_d$, then the charges in that volume $dV$ will move a distance ${dx}=v_d{dt}$. Therefore,

$$dQ=nqv_dA{dt}$$

Since the current is $I=\frac{dQ}{dt}$ we have $$I=nqv_dA$$

Now let's move towards what you have. If the wire is uniform, then $A=\frac VL$ where $L$ is the length of the wire. Therefore, $$I=\frac NV qv_d\frac VL =\frac{Nqv_d}{L}$$

Rearranging this we get $$Nq=\frac{IL}{v_d}$$

If we wanted to define a total charge carried in the wire as $Nq=Q$ then we get what you were asking about. You just have to keep in mind that this $Q$ is different than the amount of charge that is passing through the area we were looking at earlier. You also should notice that if we have a different carrier density (for example, our wire is made of a different material), then we get a different current. This is lost in the final formula we arrive at.

As you can see, you need to assume things about the system such as uniform current and carrier densities. You also need to be aware of what each variables physically means. But once you do it all works out.

Comment: @nasu Am I correct in my understanding of the physical representation of the variables here now? I really just want to make sure I understand everything correctly. I always want to learn more and be better at explaining physics to others.

Comment: With this significance of Q (the total free charge in the conductor)  I think it make sense. I don't know how useful would be. The free charge density in a conductor (and so the total charge as well) is the same even if there is no current flowing through the conductor.   On the other hand the charge "carried" through a section in a given time obviously depends on the value of the current. So the Q in your formula is not the same as Q in the OP.

Comment: @nasu yes I agree with you on all of those points.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. First of all you can write anything in mathematical exp. until and unless it's is validates. Ampere's law and biot-savart law is holding up that equation. I think it is valid but some external factors must be there like +C (for constant).

Comment: What do you think is the meaning of "x" in that equation?